# JTable in User Interface

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need help understanding how JTable can be implemented. My JTable does not show up when given header names and data, I have tried pack() (makes my everything but my menu disappear), I have tried setFillsViewportHeight(true) and nothing updated. Any help or guidance would be appreciated.

```
// Main
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Main window = new Main("A Project");
    window.setBounds(30, 30, 700, 500);
    window.setVisible(true);
}


// Displays a box with a menu bar that has file and about options(code not shown):

public Main(String title) {
    JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar(); // Window menu bar
    setTitle(title);
    setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setJMenuBar(menuBar); // Add the menu bar to the window
}

// This section of code is inside action listener when you click menu bar's file then load a file:
// Nothing appears:

String[] columnNames = {"ID","First Name","Last Name","Program","Level","USERNAME"};
        ArrayList[][] data = loadFileRoster.getRosterData();
        JTable table = new JTable(data,columnNames);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(); 
        table.add(scrollPane);
        table.setVisible(true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ArrayList[][] data = loadFileRoster.getRosterData();
    JTable table = new JTable(data,columnNames);
```

I'm not aware that you can create a JTable using an ArrayList containing your data (unless is new in JDK 14)

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(); 
    table.add(scrollPane);
```

You don't add a scroll pane to a table. You add a `JTable` to the `JViewport` of a `JScrollPane`. This is done by using:

```
    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( table );
```

You then add the scroll pane to the frame.

```
    table.setVisible(true);
```

Swing components are visible by default. The setVisible(true) is unnecessary.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Tables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html) for working examples.

Download the example and modify them. They will show you how to better structure your code.